# Rotate MPMoviePlayerController to Landscape - iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller, rotation, landscape

I am trying to rotate my MPMoviePlayerController to landscape view, but it always stays in portrait mode. I am doing this in a UIViewController and I still can't rotate my MPMoviePlayerController when I am in full screen mode. Do I have to do something to the shouldAutorotatetoOrientation method? If anyone knows how to do this please leave a reply back!!

Thanks,

Kevin

Answer (score 5):

From the [UIViewController class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> By default, the UIViewController class displays views in portrait mode only. To support additional orientations, you must override the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: method and return YES for any orientations your subclass supports. If the autoresizing properties of your views are configured correctly, that may be all you have to do. However, the UIViewController class provides additional hooks for you to implement additional behaviors as needed.

For example, if your `autoresizingMask` is set to `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight`, and the parent view of your movie player view has `autoresizesSubviews = YES`, then returning YES from the `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` may be all you need to do.

Comment: Thanks, but I've manually got it to work by shaping my view to lanscape dimensions and rotating my MPMoviePlayerController. But now I've led to the problem where my done button isn't working when I enable the [moviePlayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleFullScreen];

Answer (score 0):

i found this way only useful but it is timetaking to set the desired frame-

```
theMovie=[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:theURL]; 
// Rotate the view for landscape playback   
[[theMovie view] setBounds:CGRectMake(-230, 155, 480, 350)];
[[theMovie view] setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / 2)];
```